# How to delete different column names with duplicated values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-itertools

Given this DF:

```
a   b   c   d
1   2   1   4
4   3   4   2
foo bar foo yes
```

What is the best way to delete same columns but with different name in a large pandas DF? For example:

```
a   b   d
1   2   4
4   3   2
foo bar yes
```

Column c was removed from the above dataframe becase a and c where the same column but with different name. So far I tried to

```
df = df.iloc[:, ~df.columns.duplicated()]
```

However it is not clear to me how to check the row values inside the DF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `transpose` as below

```py
df.T.drop_duplicates().T
```

I tried straight forward approach - loop through column names and compare each column with rest of others. Use `np.all` for exact match. These approach took only 336ms.

```py
repeated_columns = []
for i, column in enumerate(df.columns):
    r_columns = df.columns[i+1:]
    for r_c in r_columns:
        if np.all(df[column] == df[r_c]):
            repeated_columns.append(r_c)
new_columns = [x for x in df.columns if x not in repeated_columns]
df[new_columns]
```

It will give you following output

```
     a    b    d
0    1    2    4
1    4    3    2
2  foo  bar  yes
```

Comment: yes, this one works, however it is slow, is there any other faster alternative

Comment: I edited my answer with another approach, it took only 336ms for 11.7MB csv file data.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.loc[:,~df.T.duplicated()]
     a    b    d
0    1    2    4
1    4    3    2
2  foo  bar  yes
```